# MVP, Request Factory and what's else?

Tags: design-patterns

I am not very familiar with design pattern. I develop an GWT webapp thanks to GWTP. I use the MVP and Request factory pattern. I am asking myself if it is enought for my webapp ? Indeed, I see my webapp as a CRUD application because main functionalities are about :

- add/del "group/permission/role"
- add/del "article/photo"
- add/del "topics/categories/destinations"
- add/del "ads"
- ...

I know there is many design pattern (factory, composite...) but I do not know if I need them in my case and I have difficulties to know how to adapt them. Can I try to developp my app just with the MVP and Request Factory pattern (GWTP / Request Factory / Objectify) ?
Thx.

Comment: I forgot to said that I will use GAE (NoSQL) so I do not know if I need to do an UML design for this ? Does the UML is related to the database or to the Oriented Object 'view' of the persistance Layer ? I am very confused...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this post http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/

Anyway, from you question it seems that you have some confusion in mind. Try following the above post, step by step, just to make something working. Things will get clearer step by step.

Basically I can say that you don't need UML per se. Just leave it for now.